# Align to the right

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/59MWq/11/

How do i align the menu to the right instead of to the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand correctly - that you want the dropdown button and the dropdown menu on the RHS of the screen, then it looks like you need `float: right;` in `.navigation`, and `right: 0;` in `.dropdown`

This is because your dropdown is absolutely positioned; an alternative solution is to put `float: right;` on both classes, and `clear: right;` on `.dropdown` to force it to be below the Account link.

Comment: if you make it `right: 10px;` then the dropdown box lines up with the right edge of the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css

```
.menu div
{
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: That just moves the navigation, it does not move the dropdown along with it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, a 'float:right;' to the menu div does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

float the navigation div to the right. also put right: 10px; on the dropdown.

```
.navigation {
    float:right;
}
.dropdown {
    right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/59MWq/29/
?